# visual basic access with database

Tags: vb.net

Hereis my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _byval As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dbProvider As String
        Dim dbSource As String
        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        [b]dbSource = "Data Source  =  \AddressBook1" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath[/b]

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        con.Open()

        MsgBox("Database is now open")

        con.Close()

        MsgBox("Database is now Closed")
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the 8th line where I specify the data source I have put for the source: dbSource = "Data Source  =  \AddressBook1" & My.Application.Info.Directory Path   because when I used it with a previous xml database  every time I copied the folder and installed on another computer it worked..so I have adjusted it with my access database now but unfortunately I get an error when in con.open "NOT A VALID FILE NAME"..the name s correct ,I have also checked the spelling and the folder which is in the application bin folder.

Any ideas or similar command to my.application.info.directory so that I will not have trouble installing it on another computer?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the textual value of `dbSource` after that statement runs?

Comment: what do you mena textual..sorry i am not ewxperienced with thiese terms.

Comment: i mean what is the final value, what actually gets passed to the connection

Comment: since i am not experienced with vb net.......i guess that the  My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath checks the folder of the project and the addressbook1 which is the database is passed together with the previous command to the data source and all together to the dbsource as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the string - spaces can cause problems:

```
dbSource = "Data Source  =  ""\AddressBook1" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & """"
```

Comment: unfortunately again the same error.although it compiles well.

Comment: any reason you don't have a drive specification?

Comment: in my original message i specify the reason..which is if i declare  c://desktop of my computer and then after compiling it and install it on another computer database will not work..while with this way i managed to do it usind an xml file.so i am lookinf fro a way to do this with an access database.

Comment: Can you give the value for 'dbSource'?

Comment: dbsource is as string

Comment: Guys in other words if it so difficult...here is what i did with my previous xml file... i first declared : Private xmldatabasedata As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\AddressBook.xml"  which was y xml file and when the form loaded  :    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(xmldatabasedata) = True Then
            DataSet1.ReadXml(xmldatabasedata)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: with the command dataset1.readxml it read the xml file which was created......I want to do the same but with an access database that is what i am asking..

Comment: What is the value of dbsource?

Comment: NEver mind gyus i figured it out my self...what i wanted if you have read my post,was how to create a database which when the programms compiles it would include in the same folder the database and would be working,which i did with xml file and i wanted somethng similar with access....By the way the solution is :    mystr = ("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\mydatabase.mdb")...Thanks  anyway..